# Spawn Long Running Background Task In Python

Tags: python, bash, flask

I am trying to setup a Flask app that will run a shell script when it receives a request. The purpose of this is to re-deploy another app when I push to GitLab. I have everything connected, but for some reason the subprocess spawned by the Flask app gets terminated shortly after it starts. I've been logging into my server over SSH to start the Flask app, and everything works fine as long as I stay logged in, but once I kill the session it stops working.

Flask app

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, Response
import os
import subprocess
from waitress import serve

process:subprocess.Popen = None

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',  methods = ['POST'])
def deploy():
    req_secret = request.headers.get("X-Gitlab-Token")
    if req_secret is not None:
        if 'DEPLOY_SECRET' in os.environ:
            if os.environ['DEPLOY_SECRET'] == req_secret:
                global process
                if process is not None:
                    process.terminate()
                process = subprocess.Popen("./deploy.sh", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                return 'Success'
    abort(401)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, port=5000)
```

deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
killall server
cd ..
git pull origin master
diesel migration run
cargo run
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
DEPLOY_SECRET=$1 pipenv run python autodeploy.py
```

`cargo run` should run forever, and it does as long as I stay logged into my SSH session. I start the flask app by running `./run &`

Comment: you probably don't want to run your flask app directly like that. things like tornado or gunicorn are better suited for production

Comment: I'm running it with waitress, which is meant for production. https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your waitress server has no privileges to run your scripts. Try to change onwership to your scripts to 'waitress_user' like:

```
chown your_waitress_user deploy.sh
```

I am not sure for the username, probably would be 'waitress'.

Comment: I will try that, but since I'm running the python script wouldn't I be the owner? Unless I somehow lose ownership once I sign out of the session

Comment: You are running the script that starts the server. Then the server does the rest

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was to use `nohup` in the python script

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, Response
import os
import subprocess
from waitress import serve

process:subprocess.Popen = None

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',  methods = ['POST'])
def deploy():
    req_secret = request.headers.get("X-Gitlab-Token")
    if req_secret is not None:
        if 'DEPLOY_SECRET' in os.environ:
            if os.environ['DEPLOY_SECRET'] == req_secret:
                global process
                if process is not None:
                    process.terminate()
                with open("autodeploy.log", "a+") as log_file:
                    process = subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "./deploy.sh"], stdout=log_file, stderr=log_file)
                return 'Success'
    abort(401)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, port=5000)
```